# How to add AWS Cognito token to the Angular Http Interceptor

Tags: angular, promise, amazon-cognito, angular-http-interceptors

I am building a login page for my application with *AWS Cognito* and *Angular 8*. Everything works fine until I try to create `getToken()` function, it turns out that the `getSession()` method accept a **callback** instead of returning a **string**.

Which mean I have to wrap it inside a **Promise** like this:

```
export function getToken() {
  var currentUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();
  if (!currentUser) {
    // redirect to login page
  } else {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      currentUser.getSession((err, session) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else if (!session.isValid()) {
          resolve(null);
        } else {
          resolve(session.getIdToken().getJwtToken());
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

And here my **interceptor**:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) : Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        // Add token to the header.......

        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, returning a **Promise** here is not an option. So how can I add the token to the header? Or should I fetch it directly from the localStorage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return an `Observable` in the `intercept` function. `return next.handle(req);` is returning an `Observable<HttpEvent<any>>`.

You can return an `Observable` from `getToken()` with `from`:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';

export function getToken() {
  var currentUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();
  if (!currentUser) {
    // redirect to login page
  } else {
    return from(
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        currentUser.getSession((err, session) => {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          } else if (!session.isValid()) {
            resolve(null);
          } else {
          resolve(session.getIdToken().getJwtToken());
          }
        });
      });
    );
  }
}
```

And then use it in `intercept` with `mergeMap`:

```
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

return getToken().pipe(
  mergeMap((token) =>
  {
    request = request.clone(
    {
        setHeaders : { ... }
    });

    return next.handle(request);
  })
)
```

Comment: I didn't know that Promise is convertible to Observable, but please add some code for your answer with the new version of `rxjs`. There are no `fromPromise()` anymore and `mergeMap()` has to be wrapped by a `pipe()`

Comment: His suggestion looks sound, and secure because it does not keep a token around anywhere.

Comment: Please do use the access token instead of id token! https://auth0.com/blog/id-token-access-token-what-is-the-difference/